# Is there an invertible matrix $x$ such that $x a_1 x^{-1} = a_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right), a_2 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$. Is there an invertible matrix $x$ such that $x a_1 x^{-1} = a_2$? Thank you very much.

Comment: What particular topic are you studying?  Jordan forms?

Comment: Hint: permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use column vectors. Let $e_{i}$ be the standard basis vectors.

Note that $a_{1}$ acts on the $e_{i}$ as
$$
e_{1} \mapsto 0, e_{2} \mapsto e_{1}, e_{3} \mapsto 0,
$$
while $a_{2}$ acts as
$$
e_{1} \mapsto 0, e_{2} \mapsto 0, e_{3} \mapsto e_{2}.
$$

You want $x$ such that $x a_{1} = a_{2} x$.

So
$$
0 = x a_{1} e_{1} = a_{2} x e_{1},\\
x e_{1} = x a_{1} e_{2} = a_{2} (x e_{2}),\\
0 = x a_{1} e_{3} = a_{2} x e_{3}.
$$
The second equation, and the definition of $a_{2}$ suggests $x e_{1} = e_{2}$ and $x e_{2} = e_{3}$. This also satisfies the first equation. For the third you may take for instance $x e_{3} = e_{1}$ (but this is not unique, as $x e_{3} = e_{1} + \lambda e_{2}$ would also do) to obtain
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  As an example, we may take
$$
x = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}
$$